# When would a selector be "not known until runtime"?

Tags: objective-c, selector

I read an Apple doc regarding [Selectors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html) which says

> You use a selector created from a string when you want your code to send a message whose name you may not know until runtime.

I have read "not known until runtime" and similar phrases in several places -- what don't we know until runtime? If I am coding, what's hidden from me, or what don't I know?

I am confused in this concept of runtime.

Answer (score 0):

*runtime* means *when your program is running*.

***The*** runtime, by contrast, means the library code that Objective-C depends upon (essentially, all the functions starting with `objc_`, `class_`, `object_`, `protocol_`, and `sel_`; that is, those defined in `<objc/runtime.h>`).

So the documentation is telling you that, if you have a situation where e.g. a configuration file or some other piece of data tells you what selector you need to call, then you might use a selector created from a string.

Answer (score 0):

It means you can determine at runtime which selector to run:

```
- (void)first
{
}

- (void)second
{
}

- (void)third
{
}

- (void)runSelectorForNumber:(NSInteger)number
{
    NSString *selectorName;
    switch (number) {
    case 1: selectorName = @"first"; break;
    case 2: selectorName = @"second"; break;
    case 3: selectorName = @"third"; break;
    default: NSAssert(NO, @"Bad number!");
    }

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
    [self performSelector:selector withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Of course in this example you would more likely do:

```
SEL selector;
```

and then for each case do:

```
case 1: selector = @selector(first); break;
```

but I wanted to show how to do this via a string as that is what you appear to be reading about.